# sh: connect to host hostname port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: networking, server, ssh, remote-access

I have trouble connecting to a server with ssh from ubuntu 16.04. I can't get to the address online either.

When i try connecting through terminal i got the following error

> ssh: connect to host hostname port 22: Connection timed out

I can able to ping the hostname with following command `ping hostname` and following is the output for the same

```
PING hostname (ipaddress) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from ipaddress: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.689 ms
  64 bytes from ipaddress: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.689 ms
  64 bytes from ipaddress: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.630 ms
  64 bytes from ipaddress: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.682 ms
  64 bytes from ipaddress: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=0.671 ms
  64 bytes from ipaddress: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=0.707 ms
  ^C
  --- hostname ping statistics ---
  6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5086ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.630/0.678/0.707/0.024 ms
```

The output for `nmap -v hostname -Pn -p 22` pasted below.

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-09-17 10:44 IST
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 10:44
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 10:44, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 10:44
Scanning hostname (ipaddress) [1 port]
Completed Connect Scan at 10:44, 2.00s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for hostname (ipaddress)
Host is up.
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.07 seconds
```

Comment: Test if the 22 tcp port is reachable with `sudo apt install nmap; nmap -v  hostname -Pn -p 22` (from client) - If not reachable, look at the host's firewall settings and check that ssh is running

Comment: I have edited the question and pasted the output. How to find if its reachable or not